# Magento\Review\Block\Product\View\ListView with constructor breaks block

Tags: magento2, dependency-injection, di

I extend `Magento\Review\Block\Product\View\ListView` with my own custom class, called `Review`.

As learned I need to extend the constructor with the same data that gets used in `Magento\Review\Block\Product\View`, which is extended by `ListView`.

However, as soon as I bring a constructor into my code, it fails. The question is: **why?**

`Review.php` (Custom Extend):

```
<?php

namespace MS\RealReviews\Block;

/**
 * Entity rating block
 *
 */

class Review extends \Magento\Review\Block\Product\View\ListView
{

    protected $customer_id;
    protected $_orderCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(    
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Url\EncoderInterface $urlEncoder,
        \Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product $productHelper,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductTypes\ConfigInterface $productTypeConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\Locale\FormatInterface $localeFormat,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency,
        \Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
        parent::__construct(
             $context, 
             $urlEncoder,
             $jsonEncoder,
             $string,
             $productHelper,
             $productTypeConfig,
             $localeFormat,
             $customerSession,
             $productRepository,
             $priceCurrency,
             $collectionFactory,
             $data
        );
    }

    protected function _setCustomerID($input){
        $this->customer_id = $input;
    }

    protected function _getCustomerID(){
        return $this->customer_id;
    }

    public function isRealReview($customer_id){

        $html = '';
        $product = $this->getProductId();
        $this->_setCustomerID($customer_id);

        $html .= $this->_getCustomerID();


        return $html;
    }

}
```

If I delete the constructor from the code, it works again. How can I fix that?

Comment: Did you try to clear the `var/generation` folder after adding the constructor ?

Comment: I'm at developer mode, so there isn't really a need for that AFAIK

Comment: you still need to clear that `var/generation` folder manually even in dev mode as soon as you modify the constructors of classes

Comment: Cool. Actually that seemed to work. Thanks, Raphael. If you write an answer with that and maybe a little more detail I'm happy to mark it as the correct answer to help others in the future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to clear the `var/generation` code.

This is indeed required as soon as you start dealing with class constructors, you can find out more here in the official documentation: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/php/php_clear-dirs.html

Comment: Using `$ rm -rf var/generation/*` has worked perfectly fine. Magento2 could handle this a little better IMHO, but its fine. Thanks for the hint, Raphael.